# How to get data from multiple nested serializer?

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

**serializer**

```py
class CarrGetOrderDetails(serializers.Serializer):
    order = CarrGetOrderDetail(required=False)
    template = CarrGetOrderDetailTemplate(required=False, many=True)
    extra_fields = CarrGetOrderDetailExtraFields(required=False, many=True)
```

**View File**

```py
class CarrierOrderDetails(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        order_id = request.GET['order_id']
        #order_obj = Order.objects.filter(id=order_id)

        obj = self.get_objects(order_id)
        #print('#####',obj)
        serializ = CarrGetOrderDetails(obj, many=True)
        return Response(serializ.data)

    def get_objects(self, order_obj):
        model1 = Order.objects.filter(id=order_obj)
        model2 = OrderTemplate.objects.filter(id=1)
        model3 = OrderExtraField.objects.filter(id=1)
        obj = {'order': model1, 'template': model2, 'extra_fields': model3}
        return obj
```

here i'm try to hit multiple serializer objects but got null data in serializer.data

**Output**

```
[
{},
{},
{}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your serializer with `many=True`, so it is expecting a list of objects. You should either pass in a list of objects as the first argument to the serializer class constructor or remove the `many=True` kwarg.

Also, since you are passing in a dictionary, I would use the `data={...}` kwarg instead of the first argument which is `instance`.

As a quick test, you can perform the following modification:

```
obj = self.get_objects(order_id)
serializ = CarrGetOrderDetails(obj, many = True)
```

```
obj = self.get_objects(order_id)
serializ = CarrGetOrderDetails(data=[obj], many = True)
```

References

- [DRF Serializer Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)
- [`serializers.py:BaseSerializer`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L86)

Comment: thanks for reply!!  i tried to make change but problem is Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got QuerySet.

Comment: Now you are onto the next issue. Your order field is many=False, but you are passing a list of objects via queryset. You can either make the field many=True or only provide it a single object by appending .first() to the order filter in your get objects function.